# Java numeric types to as3 types

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, types

I need to transfer numbers in binary format using a bytearray from java to flash but
flash as3 does not support floats and longs.

So how can I do that since it looks messy even when I try to convert java long to double and back?

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> {
>     long l = Long.MAX_VALUE/100;
>     Double d= l;
>
>     System.out.println("long  : " + l);
>     System.out.println("double: " + (long)d);
> }
> ```

```
run:

long  : 92233720368547758

double: 92233720368547760

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Long number lost it's original value after converted to double!

Comment: that is the nature of floating point.  not all longs are exactly representable as doubles.

Comment: AS3 does support Java `Long` and `Double` when using AMF serialization. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: AS3 does support floating point as `Number` [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html), though it does have limitations. That said, you're not the only one struggling with this. [link](http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/183)

Comment: the problem is that I cannot convert a double to long in order to be compatible with as3 that only supports Number type that is same to java double.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is imprecise. Flash supports floats. `Number` class in AS3 is the `double` in Java, the IEEE-754 double precision 64-bit float point. However, it has no `long`. `Number` is enough to store the Java `float`, because this is also a float but of a smaller magnitude (it only takes 32 bits). Flash can read and write these values into ByteArray, but doesn't have a correspondent type in the type hierarchy.

It is not possible to have exact analogy of Java `long`, because the format that stores a floating point number reserves some bits for other purposes, actually using only 52 bits to save the value of the float.

What you can do in Flash, if you really need long:

- Simple: use two integers.
- Complex: there are couple of classes for long math, that don't limit you to some arbitrary chosen number of bits, i.e. you can do math on numbers by far exceeding 64 bits. These are traditionally called BigInt or some such. Google should find at least couple of implementations. Search for cryptography libraries, almost every one of them needs this class to operate.

*Some information you may find useful:*

**Java primitives:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

**Flash top-level classes (which also include all numeric types):**

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package-detail.html#classSummary (unfortunately, they are listed together with other top-level classes, but there aren't too many of them to make it really difficult).

Answer (score 0):

In action script you have to use the "Number" type.

var myNumber:Number;
myNumber = Number.MAX

Comment: to be more precise,  this one returns different value from the original System.out.println("double: " + new Double(92233720368547758l*1.0).longValue());   it returns "92233720368547760"